# Не выполняется цикл while должным образом

Tags: python, циклы, while, pyautogui

Я полный чайник в питоне. Написал дилетантский код для спама с помощью модуля **pyautogui**, прописал цикл *while*, чтобы строчка из текстового файла была написана определенное количество раз (10 раз), запускаю программу, а текст печатается лишь один раз. Терминал багов не показывает. Будьте добры, подскажите, где ошибка?

```
import time, pyautogui
time.sleep(2)
a = 0
def name():
    for word in f:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
f = open("spammer2.txt", "r")
while True:
    name()
    a += 1
    if a <= 10:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Все происходит, как и написано: если `а` меньше или равно 10, то завершить цикл. В первой итерации `а` равно 1, а это меньше 10...

Comment: Увидел ошибку, поменял <= на >=, но результат всё тот же.

Comment: Потому что строчка читается один раз, а после этого курсор уже стоит в конце файла и читать нечего. Не надо читать каждый раз, нужно прочитать один раз и сохранить в переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы в `while` в `if` передали неверное условие для `break`. Должно быть так:

```
while True:
    name()
    a += 1
    if a == 10:
        break
```